# Why opencv2 has two kinds of programming styles?

Tags: opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example

```
  cv::imshow(WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
```

and

```
  cvShowImage( "Image", pImg );
```

How to know which style should I use?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12595/why-opencv2-has-two-kinds-of-programming-styles?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first is OpenCV in C++, the second is OpenCV in the basic C functions. The first example is calling the C++ version of OpenCv with namespaces and all of the functions included in the namespace. The second style is simply the OpenCV function in C. The C++ is just a wrapper for the C code, so you're essentially calling the same functions either way. Which you use is really up to you. I like the C functions better, mostly for the sake of simplicity and documentation.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-01-11**:
The latter isn't a C macro; it's a C function. It's two kinds of programming styles because C and C++ are two different languages.